# Friction as a Centripetal Force on a disk

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, centripetal-force

Consider the following:

A rock is on a horizontal disk that rotates at a constant speed about the disk's vertical axis.

Apparently the centripetal force in this case is friction.
But from my knowledge, friction only occurs when there is another force opposing friction. So what is that other force, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> But from my knowledge, friction only occurs when there is another force opposing friction.

This is mistaken. Friction acts to prevent or oppose relative motion.

In the absence of friction the rock would move in a straight line while the disk moved in a circle under it. That would be relative motion, so it is something for friction to oppose.

---

To give a couple more examples where no opposing force exists, but which might be more intuitive consider:

- A block that has been set in motion on a tabletop and slides to a halt. Once the influence that started the block is withdrawn but before it has stopped there is still friction with no opposing force.
- A box of cereal dropped straight onto a conveyor belt. It is friction with the belt that gives it a horizontal acceleration and again there is no opposing force.

Comment: but shouldn't the friction still act in the opposite direction of the tangential velocity

Comment: No, it acts in the opposite direction of the *relative motion*. Because friction opposes relative motion. Now analyzing what direction that is requires a bit of care, but for the rock to follow the disk around in a circle the force has to be radial.

Comment: is there a good way to see this? I am having trouble visualizing this.